# Mysql join two tables with counpe oft the different type of records

Tags: mysql

I'm having two table sendmail and campaign tables in mysql. Sendmail table represents the both successfully sent and failed status in stats field. And campaign filed having the campaign table id as reference. I'm trying to display how many mails had been sent successfully and failed in each campaign. 
My Two table structure are,
sendmail table[image]

campaign table structure as 
[image]
And my expected result:

```
campaigname        totalsent totalunsend

aaaa               0          1
Supply Chain       6          0
Development        6          0
Design&development 8          3
```

Comment: Would you mind to add examples to http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  campaign.name,
  SUM(status=1) totalsent,
  SUM(status=0) totalunsent
FROM
  campaign INNER JOIN sendmail
  ON campaign.campaignid = sendmail.campaignid
GROUP BY
  campaign.name
```